# How do I make a Read More Toggle within H tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm having trouble with selectors I think. Here's what I'm trying to do. I have several H3 tags with an a href within them that are above paragraphs of text. The paragraphs all have a class that hides them. I want to be able to click the link and have only the hidden div for that specific h3 open. Everything I've tried either toggles all the hidden divs (since they share a class) or they can't be within the h3. That's the trouble with this code here, it doesn't work unless I have the a tags outside of the H3 which is bad code.

Here's the html:

```
<h3><a class="expander" href="#">Headline</a></h3> 
<div class="hidden-text"> 
<p>some text here....</p>
</div>

<h3>same thing on down...
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.expander").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".hidden-text").toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire thing in a container and set the context for the anchor tag selector and put an id to the div tag and set it in the rel attribute of the anchor tag. Something like

```
<div id="divID">
    <h3><a class="expander" href="#" rel="#divHidden1">Headline</a></h3> 
    <div id="divHidden1" class="hidden-text"> 
        <p>some text here....</p>
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
    $("a.expander","#divID").click(function() {
      var div = $(this).attr("rel");
      $(div).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked great...however, it'll be a bit more difficult for the client as they have to specify an ID for each, I'd rather have it just work based on the classes so it's easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("a.expander").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next(".hidden-text").toggle();
});
```

Comment: This works better but I have to click twice to get it to toggle, sometimes 3 times to get it to close. Thoughts?

Comment: I think you can add `$('.hidden-text').hide();` before `...toggle();` to make sure all of hidden-text set to hide.